# Why aren't these variables printing in html view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An AngularJS app has a variable called `authenticated2` that needs to be accessible in an html view.  But the value is not printing out in the screen.

What specific changes can be made to the code below to make sure that the value of `authenticated2` is printed out on the screen?

Here is the relevant html:

```
auth.authenticated2 is: {{ auth.authenticated2 }} <br>
authenticated2 is {{ authenticated2 }} <br>
$scope.authenticated2 is {{ $scope.authenticated2 }} <br>
<div ng-show="auth.authenticated2=='yes'">
    <h1>Show some stuff.</h1>
</div>
```

As it stands, nothing is printed out when the above html view is loaded.  But the controller is hooked up to the view because other objects in the view are loaded based on other variables in the controller.

Here is the relevant stuff in the `security.js` controller:

```
angular.module('secure', ['auth']).controller('secure', function($scope, $http, $sce, auth) {

    $scope.authenticated1 = function() {
        if(auth.authenticated1=='yes'){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }

    $scope.authenticated2 = function() {
        if(auth.authenticated2=='yes'){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }

    //bunch of unrelated stuff

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        //bunch of unrelated stuff
    }

});
```

And here is the relevant stuff from `auth.js`:

```
angular.module('auth', ['ngCookies']).factory('auth', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $location, $cookies){
    var auth = {

        authenticated1 : $cookies['AUTH1'],
        authenticated2 : $cookies['AUTH2'],

        //bunch of unrelated stuff  

        init : function(homePath, loginPath, logoutPath) {
            //bunch of unrelated stuff
        }
    };
    return auth;
}]);
```

Comment: Could you build a plunker with the error? It would be useful!

Comment: You have used authenticated as a function while expecting a variable in html view. Change it to call as shown in answer by @pherris

Comment: @Mani That does not address the need to get the independent printout of `auth.authenticated2`.  See comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `authenticated2` is a function, you'd have to invoke it:

```
{{ authenticated2() }}
```

but it seems like you could get away with putting `auth` (or parts of it) on `$scope` and using it directly. e.g in your controller:

```
$scope.auth = auth;
```

and in your HTML:

```
{{ auth.authenticated2 }}
```

It's a bit confusing with `auth.authenticated2` (not a function) and `$scope.authenticated2` (function).

Comment: `{{ authenticated2() }}` works.  But `{{ auth.authenticated2 }}` still does not.  Do I need to add something to the controller to get `{{ auth.authenticated2 }}` to work?

Comment: You'd have to add `auth` to `$scope` - not sure if you saw my edit to the answer where I added the line `$scope.auth = auth;` for the controller.

Comment: Adding `$scope.auth=auth;` to the `secure.js` controller did not cause `{{ auth.authenticated2 }}` to print any value.  However, the Network tab of the FireFox developer tools shows that the `[AUTH2]` cookie is populated with `yes`.  I am doing all of this so that I can reliably tell in the view whether or not `["AUTH2"]` is `yes`, though simply printing out the value of `auth.authenticated2` would be sufficient for this question.  As it stands, I cannot get an independent reading of `auth.authenticated2` yet.  What else can I try?

Comment: Since `auth` is a module, you may need to reference just the value you want from it. For example `$scope.authenticated1 = auth.authenticated1` (removing the current assignment to that variable `$scope.authenticated1 = function() { ... }`), then just '{{ authenticated1 }}' in your HTML.

Comment: Putting `authenticatedTwo is: <br> {{authenticatedTwo}}` in the view and `$scope.authenticatedTwo = auth.authenticated2;` in the controller still fails to print out a value in the view, even though the FireFox Network tab says that the value of the `["AUTH2"]` cookie is `yes`.  What else can I try?

Comment: I get that your problem is authenticated2 is asynchronously loaded while your controller is initialized early. try to return a promise from auth factory and set to authenticatedTwo anywhere you like

Comment: I thought maybe it was async too, but the sample code doesn't seem to indicate it. Since it's an existing cookie I believe the read-only operation is synchronous but it's a good question, let's see what the OP says.

Comment: @pherris The OP says that changing `$cookies['AUTH2'];` to `$cookies.get('AUTH2');` got your `$scope.authenticatedTwo = auth.authenticated2;` to work, though adding two populating lines to `auth.init()` also may have affected it, as per Mani's suggestion.  So your code works when I updated to `1.4.x` syntax for cookies.  Thank you and +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is about getting auth variable in scope, I can suggest you to set the variable auth in some init.

```
angular.module('secure', ['auth']).controller('secure', 
function($scope, $http, $sce, auth) {

    init();

    function(){
        //It is good to have an init method if you have some sigin activies
        //before setting every variable else where

        $scope.auth ={};

        auth.getLoginInfo().then(function(res){
            var auth = {};
            auth.authenticated2 = res.authenticated2;
            $scope.auth = auth;
        });
    }

    $scope.authenticated1 = function() {
        if(auth.authenticated1=='yes'){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }

    $scope.authenticated2 = function() {
        if(auth.authenticated2=='yes'){return true;}
        else{return false;}
    }

    //bunch of unrelated stuff

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        //bunch of unrelated stuff
    }

});
```

In your HTML it remains same as:

```
auth.authenticated2 is: {{ auth.authenticated2 }} <br>
authenticated2 is {{ authenticated2() }} <br>
<div ng-show="auth.authenticated2=='yes'">
 <h1>Show some stuff.</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get `auth.getLoginInfo()`.  Do I need to add that to `auth.js`?

Comment: firstly, you didn't actually declare an `init()` method here though you tried to call it, and secondly, the controller function **already is a constructor function**. this is not only redundant, but not necessary.

Comment: @Claies First there is a init() declared inside controller. Secondly an init() provides as an initialization method. It is a style guide and not a necessity,  from https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide. Please refer there before saying it.

Comment: @CodeMed yeah, you need to add that in your auth.js and you need to return a promise from that factory method.

Comment: @Mani Can you please humor me and show me the code that you mean?  For example, adding the following two lines to the existing `auth.init()` did not result in anything printed out on the screen using the same html stuff shown above: `authenticated1 = $cookies['AUTH1'];  authenticated2 = $cookies['AUTH2'];`

Comment: where in the papa style guide does it say you should use an `init()` function?  and no, you didn't declare an `init()` function here, you *called* an `init();` and then wrote a random `function()` statement as the next line.

Comment: @Claies Any method or module have an init method.

Comment: that doesn't even make sense, but even if you were right, the code you posted here clearly didn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: @Claies I dont know why you have downvoted it but this is definitely not a wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for offering a different approach.  Please see my comment at the end of the other answer to see how I resolved this.